# is possible to check if a fb user have a credit card linked to his account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-payment-dialog

im developing an Facebook canvas game application and i want to know if a fb user have a credit card linked to his account? if the condition is true the payment-dialog will show up on screen.. 
otherwise the functionality of the app will change depending if the user have a credit card or not. is there any fb api call that give this information?

Comment: No there is no way for you to know of course

Comment: @WizKid great thanks.